# Is it possible to upload .stp files (Autodesk Inventor 2010 files) to a SharePoint 2010 list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We would like to be able to upload files with a .std extension to a list on our SharePoint Foundation site, but get an error message when we try: "Unable to read cabinet info from". I assume it is because SharePoint templates use the same extension.

My question is thus, is there a way to enable upload files with .stp extension without breaking SharePoint, possibly on a list-by-list basis?

Best regards, Egil.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the STP extension is the web/list template extension of SharePoint, which is basically a CAB (cabinet) file (a kind of compressed file format). SharePoint will attempt to open the cabinet to extract data from it, such as template title and language. As your STP files are in the wrong format, this fails. I would suggest changing the extension prior to uploading (e.g. zip the files).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The solution you suggest is not really an option for though, the users do not want the extra steps just to share a file.